# AWS Elastic Load Balancer (Public To Internal)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elb

I am trying to build up a multi-tiered architecture on AWS.

I have a public facing ELB which has my autoscale webserver instances running on docker. I also have in my private subnet backend servers running on docker containers behind an internal elb.

I need my public facing elb to forward some request to the backend servers via the internal elb but am on-sure on how that can work. According to the doc below this can work.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-internal-load-balancers.html

Anyone achieved this before who can provide assistance?

Comment: What type of load balancer, an Application Load Balancer? How will the load balancer know which requests need to go to which instances? You can't point a load balancer to another load balancer (note how the article you linked doesn't show that). An application load balancer can send different requests to different instance target groups, which may accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have the following resources:

- 1 Public facing ELB
- 2+ Web servers in autoScaling and the application is deployed in Docker
- 1 Private ELB
- 2+ backend servers

Query:-
How to forward the requests from public facing ELB to internal ELB.

Solution and suggestion:

You cannot directly Route the request from ELB to ELB. In your webserver you have to mention the internal ELB endpoint to route the traffic to your private ELB.